# regex OR/ALTERNATIVE help

Tags: regex

Need a little help with a regex

I'm trying to match a string that falls at the begging or end of a larger string,  or follows or is followed by whitepace. Or any combination of the two.

(Basically I want to find a particular string, but only match it if it is not part of another word or phrase.  IE  if the string I was searching for was "are" I wouldn't want to match "are" in the word "area",  hence either beginning or end of searched string, or follows or is followed by whitespace.)

Here is what I have now:

```
re.compile('^(%(string)s)$|\s(%(string)s)$|^(%(string)s)\s|\s(%(string)s)\s' % {'string': my_string})
```

Is there a less verbose way of writing this using two |'s .  One at the beging for start or whitespace, and one at the end for end or whitespace?

Write now I am writing out every permutation of beginning options * end option and figure its less efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your search term with `\b`s:

```
\bstring\b
```

`\b` matches a word boundary, and importantly is "zero-width" (consumes no characters)

Comment: thank you, regex is one of those things where you can know exactly what you are looking for, and it seem impossible to find the answer